# How to detect an HTML file that had extension changed to Excel .xls

Tags: java, file, apache-tika

I have a java app that processes excel files from emails in an automated fashion (.xls, xlsx etc). I've noticed that some files are not native files. Opening in Excel will give a warning that the file is corrupt/badly formated. Opening in notepad++ clearly shows HTML

Unfortunately I can't just manually handle these files so I need a way to automatically spot them.

I noticed that when I use java.io.fiile object then with org.apache.tika.Tika I can detect the the type. So with the file object I can find out the extension, and with tika.detect() i can find that the format is called "text/html". (Not sure if this is the best way, but it seems to work with my singular example)

So I can then find these kinds of files using:

```
File file = getTheFileObject();
if ( tika.detect(file).equalsIgnoreCase("text/html") && file.getName().contains(".xls") ) { ... do what I want with the corrupt file... }
```

My problem comes when doing something similar with email attachments. To get the file from emails I'm using the com.microsoft.ews-java-api 2.0 and from this I can get a FileAttachment object which represents the file.

But when I attempt to use tika.detect() on this (same corrupt file) i get a different format output "application/octet-stream" instead of "text/html". Or get "application/vnd.ms-excel" using the FileAttachments own methods

How can I spot these corrupt files if I can't spot the html formated xls files?

```
FileAttachment attachment = getFileAttachment();
attachment.getContentType() //application/vnd.ms-excel
tika.detect(attachment.getContentStream()) //application/octet-stream
```

How would I spot an html file that has .xls file extension from the emails ews FileAttachment object? Will tika still help?

Comment: If you save the attachment out to a file, and run Tika on that, does it get detected correctly? Is there any headers in front of the HTML from the email? What version of Tika are you using?